# Multiple clients posting data in node js

Tags: node.js, post, request

I've read that in Node js one should treat POST requests carefully because the post data may arrive in chunks, so it has to be handled like this, concatenating:

```
function handleRequest(request, response) {
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        request.on('end', function () {
            //data is complete here
        });
    }
}
```

What I don't understand is how this code snippet will handle several clients at the same time. Let's say two separate clients start uploading large POST data. They will be added to the same body, mixing up the data...

Or is it the framework which will handle this? Triggering different instances of handleRequest function so that they do not get mixed up in the body variable?

Thanks.

Comment: Your desired transport protocol will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

Given the `request, response` signature of your method, it looks like that's a listener for the [request event](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_request).

Assuming that's correct, then this event is emitted for every new request, so as long as you are only concatenating new data to a `body` object that is unique to that handler (as in your current example), you're good to go.